# C# SSH.net Cisco Connection

Tags: c#, ssh, cisco

I want to write a program with C # with which I can execute standardized commands on a Cisco switch. To set up an SSH connection, I use SSH.net. Unfortunately my program doesn't work. I am not sure whether the SSH connection will be established at all. In any case, the commands mentioned are not carried out.
Unfortunately, I am a novice programmer and I need your help. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Many Thanks.

Alex

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ConnectionInfo ConnNfo = new ConnectionInfo("192.168.1.1", 22, "username",
                new AuthenticationMethod[]{

                new PasswordAuthenticationMethod("username","password"),

                }
            );


            using (var sshclient = new SshClient(ConnNfo))
            {
                sshclient.Connect();

                if (!sshclient.IsConnected)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("not connect...");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("connect...");
                }

                var cmd = sshclient.RunCommand("enable");
                cmd = sshclient.RunCommand("cisco");
                cmd = sshclient.RunCommand("conf t");
                cmd = sshclient.RunCommand("int gi 1/0/2");
                cmd = sshclient.RunCommand("des Test");
                cmd = sshclient.RunCommand("exit");

                Console.ReadLine();

                sshclient.Disconnect();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: please provide more detail, what does it mean it doesnt work? any errors? did you step through it?

Comment: The program starts and the query as to whether the connection exists writes "connect...". Unfortunately, the command you requested was not executed on the switch.

Comment: perform a Console.WriteLine(cmd.Result)  after each of your RunCommand operations and look at the result of each to see what is happening.   It is possible you need to introduce a delay between each RunCommand and give the cisco cli enough time to respond to each command.

Comment: I am also getting same error and getting below error and result is blank string.

tsh:invalid options -- 'c'\n

Could someone please guide on this error?

Thanks